# Create table with Select * into with different collation

Tags: sql, t-sql, collation

I have a database (DB1) with one collation and many tables.

I've got another database (DB2) with a different collation (on another server).

I want to create copies of the tables from DB1 on DB2, but with the collation of DB2.

The tables have many columns and there are a lot of tables so I don't want to have to stick `COLLATE ....` on each column. I'd much rather be able to do `SELECT * INTO ... FROM ...`.

How can I change the collation of the columns of the new table without specifying them all individually?

I'm running MS SQL 2005.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as what I have understood this problem .. solution is -

you can use DB link .... try to link all the desired tables from DB1 and create synonym in DB2
(obviously you have to give synonym name other then the table name .. because tables with same  name will be there also in DB2)

now try to create new tables with union to DB2 tables (in other word you can say I am saying to merge the tables)